# How to send email using sendgrid in laravel

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I am trying to send the email using sendgrid in Laravel but I am not getting any email.

I have [looked](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html) into send doc for integrating send in Laravel  and followed the exact way . I have looked into other site but I am unable to receive any email.

Comment: refer : https://github.com/YasinPatel/send-email-in-laravel-using-sendgrid

Comment: What do you mean by `I have looked into other site`? Have you looked at the SendGrid activity logs, maybe it shows the email was blocked for some reason.